# Is it possible to automate sewer service line creation?

Tags: arcpy, python, arcmap

I am a GIS Tech working for a utility company, part of the asset maintenance program entails running a camera down gravity mains (sewer pipes) from the upstream manhole to the downstream manhole.

Every time the camera finds a sewer lateral (service line) it records its distance and the angle it leaves the gravity main.

I have been able to use ArcMap to plot the distances as points by converting the gravity mains to a route layer and using the create route events too on the original excel file given to me which contains the distances for each service line.

Now here is my main question - most of our gravity mains currently do not have the sewer laterals (service lines) digitized yet. With the location of the sewer lateral (point file) i also have the direction it leaves the gravity main.

Is it possible some how in arcpy to automate the creation of the sewer laterals, for example, just make all the sewer lines 20 ft and set a predetermined direction (the original points have an angle measurement for the sewer lateral direction leaving the gravity main).

Could anyone give me any direction on how I might go about automating the creation of the sewer laterals

Comment: It's possible to automate so much that, rather than asking if it's possible, it's generally more effective to just start coding. In this case, without a *known* pipe path, you'll need to modify the data schema to have a "computed" location, but the actual geometry computation is basic trigonometry.

Comment: I would argue its more productive to be given pointers rather than just ' start coding' when I have zero experience on this particular issue - but thanks for your input regardless

Comment: GIS SE is less about *pointers* and more about fixing problems. If you haven't started coding, there isn't yet anything to fix. There are so many potential solutions that we have no idea of whether the answer, if we take the tine to frame one, will be understood. If I provided ten lines of FORTRAN it might solve the linear equation, but wouldn't be of any real help. This is why we require code in coding questions, so that the answer fits the problem.

Comment: Vince, being a coding novice, I was more after direction, pointers - I never asked for a complete solution, I think you overlooked this in both of your posts, thank you again for your responses, even if they come across as quite contentious.

Comment: Many of the tools in ArcCatalog after successfully ran, can be saved as python snippets. If you have used tools from System tools to do the manual GIS work, then run one again, then right click and then copy the python code and paste it into notepad++ (you'll need to install notepad++ first, if you do not already have this tool). the snippet will give you the arcpy snippets you'll need to automate with the variables needed to pass into the function. To automate, you'll need to create a geoprocessing. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/main/analyze/geoprocessing-tools.htm

Comment: Check out the Bearing Distance to Line tool.  http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/bearing-distance-to-line.htm  You should pre-select just the points from which you want the tool to generate lines.  Add a distance field for the 20 feet if you don't already have one and calc it to 20.  A new line feature class will be generated.  Then you can use the Append tool to integrate the new lines into your master sewer line feature class.

Comment: You would also need to take into account the bearing of the underlying sewer main line in your calculation, if your angles are relative to the sewer main line. The endpoint of the laterals could also be easily calculated with `endpoint_x = startpoint_x + 20 * sin(bearing)` and `endpoint_y = startpoint_y + 20 * cos(bearing)`